# Update record based on username given in Request body

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I need to update value in Group db Group_name to the value send in Json payload.

Db schema

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: String,
    Group_name: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
    }
});

mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

And API request

```
router.put('/join', async(req, res) => {
    try {
        const data = await User.updateOne(req.params.username, {
            Group_name: req.body.Group_name
        });
        console.log(data)

        res.send({ msg: "Group Updated!!!" })

    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
        res.sendStatus(400).send('Server Error');
    }
});
```

currently its updating only first record which is incorrect , my requirement is to check for all records based on username given and according to username given in request parameters ,i will update value of Group_name to the value sent in request body.
can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify query condition.

```
const data = await User.updateOne(
    { username: req.params.username }, 
    { $set: { Group_name: req.body.Group_name } }
);
```

Comment: same issue ,It didnt help .
 router.put('/join', async(req, res) => {
    try {
        const data = await User.updateOne({ username: req.params.username }, { Group_name: req.body.Group_name });
        console.log(data)

        res.send({ msg: "Group Updated!!!" })

    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
        res.sendStatus(400).send('Server Error');
    }
});

Comment: i update my answer

Comment: Its threwing an error  SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'  at { $set: Group_name: req.body.Group_name }

Comment: I did fix by {} to group_name but still its not updating Group_name in DB router.put('/join', async(req, res) => {
    try {
        const data = await User.updateOne({ username: req.params.username }, { $set: { Group_name: req.body.Group_name } });
        console.log(data)

        res.send({ msg: "Group Updated!!!" })

    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
        res.sendStatus(400).send('Server Error');
    }
});

Comment: My request using postman : PUT request  http://localhost:3001/users/join/username=test9@gmail.com          ,in Body parameters Group_name = Group B

Answer (score 0):

First of all, understand the difference between `req.body` & `req.params`

`req.body` means hidden parameters sent in request body like in post or put requests.

`req.params` means defined paramters in URL. For this, you must have it defined in your route like below

```
router.put('/join/:username', async (req, res) => {
                // ^^^^^^^^ here it is defined, now you can access it like
    const username = req.params.username;
//or
    const {username} = req.params;   // destructuring
}
```

there is one more thing and that is

`req.query` means undefined paramters attached to URL with ?/&

If you want to give username without pre defining like `/join?username=john` then use `req.query`

```
router.put('/join', async (req, res) => {                  
    const {username} = req.query;
}
```

Then you should use `updateMany()` function instead of `updateOne()`

```
try {
    const {username} = req.params;
    const {Group_name} = req.body;
    const data = await User.updateMany(
        {username},     // find as many users where username matches
        {Group_name}    // update group name from body
    );

    console.log(data);
```

The consoled data would be like `{ n: 2, nModified: 2, ...}` because the `update` queries don't return updated documents but status of the query. If you want to get updated record set, you have to query again with `find()`.

```
// after update
const updatedRecord = await User.find({ username });
console.log(updatedRecord);
```

---

::POSTMAN::

Postman has two types of parameters

1. Params
2. Body

[image: postman request parameter types]

- If you add in ***Params*** it will be added in URL `/join?username=john@email.com&Group_name=GroupB` and you have to access it in code with `req.query.username` or `req.query.Group_name`
- If you add in ***Body*** it will be hidden and can be accessed with `req.body.Group_name` etc

Hope it helps!

Comment: thanks for explanation but still my record is not getting updated , here is my API request . router.put('/join/:username', async(req, res) => {
    try {
        const { username } = req.params;
        const data = await User.updateMany({ username }, // find as many users where username matches
            { Group_name: req.body.Group_name }
        );

        console.log(data);
        res.send({ msg: "Group Updated!!!" })
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
        res.sendStatus(400).send('Server Error');
    }


});

Comment: how are you checking the updated record? Using console?

Comment: also are you getting success or error?

Comment: see my updated answer for `req.query` because according to your comment below, you're using this method.

Comment: are you giving your parameters in **Params** of postman or **Body** ?

Comment: before update query, console to check  if you're getting username & Group_name from request!

Comment: YOur solution helped me alot . I am able to update record.
router.put('/join', async(req, res) => {
    try {
        const { username } = req.query;
        const data = await User.updateMany({ username }, { Group_name: req.body.Group_name });
        res.send({ success: true, msg: "Group Updated!!!" })
    } catch (err) {
        res.send(400).send({ success: false, msg: err });
    }


});

Comment: then mark this as the correct answer and also upvote it ***"only if it helped you more than other answers"***